# How to check active theme is parent or child wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, templates, child-theme, parent-theme

I am working on a plugin in plugin. I make template folder and in template folder and there are files of plugin that shows my post type data.

**First Scenario**

When user activate my plugin the template folder move to active theme folder. Its working perfectly.

**Second Scenario**

Now If there is parent and child theme. When the parent theme activate the template folder move to parent theme but when user activate child theme the template folder also move to child theme.

Now i want that if user activate parent theme then template folder move to parent theme but when user activate child theme then it should not be moved.

Like:

```
if(parent theme active) {
    //files moved
} else {
    // Do nothing
}
```

I search from google and found `wp_get_theme();` function but it is not fit for my work.

So is there any hook or function that i can write it and it solve my problem.

Here is my move folder function:

```
$foo_theme_dir = get_template_directory();
$foo_plugin_dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );

copy($foo_plugin_dir.'template/archive-foo_plugin.php', $foo_theme_dir.'template/archive-foo_plugin.php');
```

Comment: Did you try [is_child_theme()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L123) ?

Comment: i don't get it .... how can i use this

Comment: Maybe under the `switch_theme` or `after_switch_theme` hooks, but I might be misunderstanding your question. ps: I'm not sure `copy()` is allowed in the wordpress.org plugin repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I try this code and it solve my problem

```
if ( is_child_theme() === false ) {
    // files moved
} else {
    // do nothing
}
```

Thankx to @birgire

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
add_action( 'switch_theme', function( $new_name, $new_theme )
{
    if( is_a( $new_theme->parent(), '\WP_Theme' ) )
    {
        // Child theme was activated
    }
    else
    {
       // Parent theme was activated
    }
}, 10, 2 );
```

to see if the theme you just activated is a *child theme* or not.